# What to do about spurious regression

Tags: time-series, spurious-correlation

Say you have two variables with trends in them. It is often said that this leads to spurious regression. My question is, when will regression with ARIMA error (which may involve differencing) eliminate this problem and when instead do you have to look at issues of cointegration, for example the cointegration in ARDL or ECM models. Can you ever use regression with ARIMA error if the variables are cointegrated? Can you ever use regression with ARIMA error if the variables are integrated of different orders.